# How to select rows by time interval in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with timestamp field and usage field like this

```
            timestamp  | usage
'2015-06-13 13:45:58'  | 240
'2015-06-13 13:45:59'  | 480
'2015-06-13 13:46:00'  | 240
'2015-06-13 13:46:01'  | 320
 ...
```

I want to get sum of usage for a period of '1 week' with '30 minutes' interval. 
I can get data only for intervals in minute, hour, day and ...

```
SELECT date_trunc('minute', timestamp) as clock, sum(usage)
FROM my_table
WHERE timestamp > localtimestamp - INTERVAL '1 week'
GROUP BY clock
```

how to get data for intervals like '5 minutes', '30 minutes', '2 days' and ... .

Comment: If I get you right - you want to sum(usage) over a field that is between date_trunc('minute', timestamp) and date_trunc('minute', timestamp) + '30 minutes'::interval as a subquery, and then the upper one?.. right?..

Comment: I think that's right. I want each result's row show usage of 30 minutes.

Comment: does the below query work for you?..

Comment: @VaoTsun do you have another suggestion?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the following to get what your after.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 'epoch' + INTERVAL '1 second' * round((extract('epoch' FROM timestamp) / 1800) * 1800) AS clock,  SUM(usage)
FROM my_table 
WHERE timestamp > localtimestamp - INTERVAL '1 week'
GROUP BY round(extract('epoch' FROM timestamp) / 1800)
```

Comment: return error in line 1: "column "timestamp" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"

Comment: it is in the group by, did you copy all the code, or did you add to it?

Comment: I use pgadmin to test this query and it draws error line under 'timestamp' in this section on line one! "round((extract('epoch' FROM timestamp)" .
and about changes, I change 'timestamp' to 'time_stamp' and 'my_table' to 'records', just this!

Comment: I test this code without any change again. but the error is still. I change group by section to 'group by clock', but query return all of records.

Comment: Finally, I found problem :). you should bring out second 1800 from 'round' function and group by 'clock'. please update your answer, I want check it as a correct answer. thank you.